# SharePoint 2010 March 2019 CU

Tags: cumulative-update, patching

I just updated the March 2019 CU onto the SharePoint 2010 Infra. All went well and the upgrade completed successfully without any issues. Farm information shows 14.0.7230.5000. The link here https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224 shows 14.0.7231.5000. Is anything wrong?

Vj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, build numbers do not always match with what you see on the farm. This is fine.